# Please put the date near the top of the post

Tags: feature-request, information-display, timestamps

It is extremely time consuming to have to continually scroll down through the webpage to find the date of the post, before I begin reading the post. In gauging how relevant a post is to my particular problem, I always start with the date.

Comment: Welcome to Meta SO! Just so you know, downvotes on this site mean "I disagree with this request," not "you asked a bad question."

Comment: Just curious, which sites/topics do you frequent? I don't usually find that dates are that important.

Answer (score 2):

Most posts are short and don't extend off the screen.  Most searches and lists of questions already have dates that you can refer to before even opening the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have the "asked xx:xx" displayed in the listing of question. That is sufficient I think.

In interesting mode you also have the last activity registered.

Comment: Yes, the age of the post is readily available to you **before** you click through at all times, right at the point when you need to take it into consideration.  The only time this isn't the case is when you click through from a link in one post to another, and in this situation the age is usually not critical.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is editable here -- so the date is not as important.

We actively suppress "too localized" activity and discussion precisely for this reason, to generate artifacts of (reasonably) lasting value.

While in all fairness, we are a hybrid system, this would be akin to asking Wikipedia to put the date at the top of all their pages.

Answer (score 0):

Disagree.  I like it the way it is.

Answer (score -1):

They could insert it right above the `tagged` text on the right.